# Partial search with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I'm trying to get partial search through my index of people.

Each person has an identifier (which can be a number, string , email address) and tags (string, numbers or whatever you want to tag your users with).

I want to be able to search through the entire list and match partial string. For example, if I search for '@gmail.com' it should match all users which have '@gmail' in either their identifier or tag.

I've been trying multiple things but can't make it work for *partial* search.

I'm using the Tire ruby gem by the way.

It worked when I was using wildcard search like *gmail.com* but it was very slow.

---

```
class Person
  include Tire::Model::Search
  ...
  settings analysis: {
    analyzer: {
      email_analyzer: {
        "tokenizer" => "standard",
        "filter" => "lowercase"
      }
    }
  }

  mapping do
    indexes :identifier,  analyzer: "email_analyzer"
    indexes :email,       analyzer: "email_analyzer"
    indexes :tags_name,   analyzer: "keyword"
  end
  ...
  def tire_search(search)
    query ||= begin
      t = search.gsub(/[@\-\+\:]/, " ").strip
      t.present? ? "*#{t}*" : ""
    end
    tire.search(load: false, page: page, per_page: per_page) do
      query { string query, :default_operator => :AND, :fields => ['identifier', 'email', 'tags_name'] } if query.present?
      filter :terms, account_id: [account_id]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: do you have patterns in partial search or need any king of search???

Comment: Updated the post with relevant code